# SSIS ETL parallel extraction from a AS400 file

Tags: ssis, parallel-processing, etl, dts

Is there any way to improve the extraction from AS400 using parallelism with SSIS ETLs?

I'm migrating DTS to ETLs but the performance is so poor... obviously something can be done in order to at least match the performance (in time) of the DTS. But I have no idea how (very new on this)

Any tips please?

Comment: There are about five components to work out the bottleneck: 1. Source AS400 query returning records; 2. Network between AS400 and SSIS Server; 3. SSIS package itself; 4. Network between SSIS Server and SQL Server (usually this is local though); 5. Insertion into SQL Server. The only way you can assume SSIS is slower is if you have kept  elements 1,2,4,5 identical after the upgrade to SSIS. Is that true? Each of these elemenrts have more detail, i.e. the driver you are using to extract data from AS400

Comment: You could create multiple smaller files and import them with parallel dataflows.

Comment: What is the source AS400 query.  Never mind replace the source AS400 query with a SQL view on the AS400.  Then pull from the  SQL view.

Answer (score 0):

Parallelism in SSIS is generally done by writing the package to have multiple operations in the same space (i.e two dataflows with no control flow setting any precedence).

In theory, you could partition your query to do this (split the data in half and have a condition on each flow?). Without knowing anything about the insides of a AS400, I couldn't tell you if this would be worth doing. Potentially you could run extracts from different tables at the same time.

I dont believe that parallel extraction from a single file is possible. If you can use a direct ODBC connection to the AS400 instead, this might give a bigger performance boost over trying to tune a file export/import process.